# How to set up WebClient so that it makes multiple calls with a given buffer max limit instead of increasing the buffer max limit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webclient

To resolve the "max buffer limit reached" issue, we increased the buffer max limit and made it configurable. How can we set up webClient with a default buffer max limit to make multiple consecutive calls, given a default buffer limit, so that it can complete the webClient call?

i.e. Limit is reached when attempting to make a webClient call that returns 10k records given the bufferMaxLimit = 1. Ideally webClient would take 5k records first and then the next 5k instead of increasing the bufferMaxLimit to 2 in the properties file.

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(){
  return WebClient.builder()
         .filter()
         .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
             .builder()
             .codecs(codecs -> codecsdefaultCodecs()
                 .maxInMemorySize(bufferMaxLimit * 1024 * 1024))
             .build())
         .build();
}
```